# Bootstrap - Resize Jumbotron Image Background Coverage Based On Device Screen Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, responsive

I am using a Bootstrap jumbotron to display list results. This jumbotron uses an image as the background which is set to cover 50% of the width and 100% of the height initially. Please find below the style code implemented in the HTML div of the jumbotron:

```
style="width:80%;max-width:750px;min-height:220px;
background:url({{ property.properties_pictures.property_image1.url }});
background-size:50% 100%;background-repeat:no-repeat;
list-style-type:none;border:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#d6d0ca;"
```

I would like to inverse the coverage of the background image to 100% of the width and 50% of the height for devices that have a screen width of less than 500px.

I tried using media queries with no luck:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-min)
{
.jumbotron
{
    background-size: 100% 50%;;
}
}
```

It would be great if anyone could help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your media queries in this format--

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
.jumbotron
{
    background-size: 100% 50%;;
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi neophyte. Thanks for your answer. I have tested my CSS with your suggestion but this has not done any change. Would you know by any chance why this might be?

Comment: Where are you adding your custom css file? One problem can be it is getting overridden by bootstrap. Always add your custom css after the bootstrap css file so that in doesn't get overridden by bootstrap. One more thing don't add inline css that's a bad practice add it to your custom css file.